# Do we know what Hana is sick with?

Tags: tokyo-godfathers

In Tokyo Godfathers, we know that Hana is sick. She's shown coughing up blood several times and ends up in the hospital at one point in the movie. It's not clear to me what it is that she's sick with. I wasn't paying attention to all the details, so it could have been said, or this could have just never been revealed.

**Do we know what sickness was afflicting Hana?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never revealed outright but it is implied to be AIDS. We know that Hana used to have a boyfriend named Ken who died (and caused Hana to drift away from the drag queen club). When asked if Ken died of AIDS, Hana glibly replies "No, he slipped on the soap". So the implication is that Ken *did* die of AIDS and probably passed it on to Hana.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no. While she may not have been serious when she said he 'slipped on the soap', that doesn't automatically mean he did die of AIDS. It could be the case that Hana just didn't want to talk about it, and given the lack of gravity in the scene, it doesn't seem likely that it would be where they reveal something like that. Furthermore, even if he did contracted AIDS and died from it, that doesn't mean he passed it on. They could have been having only safe sex.

Furthermore, since it's never revealed outright, and given the only information we get from the hospital scene — which was that the lifestyle of a homeless person is making it worse, it would make much more sense that her condition wouldn't have been anything serious if she hadn't been homeless. Especially since it would ruin the entire hopeful tone of the story, and the especially upbeat ending, if one of the characters was going to die anyway.

Bronchitis, for example, would be a very bad thing for a homeless person to get, but it would be completely non-fatal to someone able to get medical attention.

> As Hana would be able to by the end, because they won the lottery.

Answer (score 0):

it could be Tuberculosis (or TB). anyone can get it, but it does spreads faster in people with AIDS. so says a quick google search. But Hana being homeless and not getting any treatment for TB (or also has AIDS) could make it worse.

it's like the Spanish THAT DOESN'T HAVE A SINGLE TRANSLATION AT ALL ANYWHERE (That I could find...)

But again who knows? Only the writers.

Comment: This is speculation not an actual answer.